# Как отображать картинки по нажатию кнопок?

Tags: java, изображения, button

Я написал простую программу, которая должна по нажатию на кнопку выводить на экран соответствующую картинку, но к моему сожалению, при нажатии ничего не происходит, картинка появляется если изменять размер окна, но появляется только последняя картинка, соответствующая последней нажатой кнопке, и больше не меняется, да и если бы менялась, то все равно программа не работала бы должным образом, как мне исправить эту проблему?

Код программы:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


  public class SPS{

    JFrame frame;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SPS gui = new SPS();
      gui.go();
    }

      public void go(){

      frame = new JFrame();

      JButton sbut = new JButton("STONE");
      sbut.addActionListener(new StoneListener());
      JButton pbut = new JButton("PAPER");
      pbut.addActionListener(new PaperListener());
      JButton scbut = new JButton("SCISSORS");
      scbut.addActionListener(new ScissorsListener());


      frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, sbut);
      frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, pbut);
      frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, scbut);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(500,500);
      frame.setVisible(true);

    }

      class StoneListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

          DrawStone st = new DrawStone();
          frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, st);
          System.out.println("STONE PRESSED");


        }
      }

      class PaperListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

          DrawPaper pp = new DrawPaper();
          frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, pp);
          pp.repaint();
          System.out.println("PAPER PRESSED");

        }
      }

      class ScissorsListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

          DrawScissors sc = new DrawScissors();
          frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, sc);
          sc.repaint();
          System.out.println("SCISSORS PRESSED");

        }
      }
    }


    class DrawStone extends JPanel {
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

        Image image = new ImageIcon("stone.jpg").getImage();
        g.drawImage(image,3,4,this);
        System.out.println("STONE DRAWED");

      }
}

  class DrawPaper extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

      g.setColor(Color.white);
      g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

      Image image = new ImageIcon("paper.jpg").getImage();
      g.drawImage(image,3,4,this);
      System.out.println("PAPER DRAWED");

    }
}

class DrawScissors extends JPanel {
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

    Image image = new ImageIcon("scissors.jpg").getImage();
    g.drawImage(image,3,4,this);
    System.out.println("SCISSORS DRAWED");

    }
  }
```